# India e-visa - arriving from different country, is that ok?

Tags: india, uk-citizens, e-visas

I'm a UK citizen, looking to go to Sri Lanka and India (in that order).  Am planning to get e-visas for both countries sorted before I go.

Is it ok to arrive in India from Sri-Lanka with my e-visa? Or do I need to arrive directly from the country I applied to the visa from (UK in this instance)

Comment: It seems very unlikely that this would be an issue. People travel from other countries all the time -- what would happen if you lived in a small country that didn't have direct flights to India, for example, or one that was too far away? And it's very common to fly via a hub such as Dubai.

Comment: Hi @DavidRicherby - have you travelled to India? In general visa/arrival issues are a bit "weird" (example, it's the only place I know of where you are sometimes asked for (all!) your boarding passes of all the flights that got you there - WTH? who keeps those?) and with the eVisa, you can't just arrive any old place, only certain airports. Additionally India is "funny" about certain countries (at the extreme, Pakistan but others also).

Comment: Welcome new user.  One unrelated problem to watch for - india is one of the countries with that infuriating "6 months" rule.   With your UK passport, you cannot get an eVisa ( https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/evisa/tvoa.html ) unless your UK passport has a full 6+ months validity remaining - so annoying.

Comment: eVisa questionnaire just asks about airport/port of entry. You apply the eVisa from an Indian Website (so nothing related to your country). You will asked your nationality and country of residence, but that are independent of the travel you may organize. it is common to enter from other countries.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter where you arrive *from*, but the Indian e-visa is only valid for entry at [specific airports and seaports](https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/evisa/tvoa.html):

> 9. e-Visa is valid for entry through 25 designated Airports (i.e. Ahmedabad, Amritsar, Bagdogra, Bengaluru, Calicut, Chennai, Chandigarh,Cochin, Coimbatore, Delhi, Gaya, Goa, Guwahati, Hyderabad, Jaipur, Kolkata, Lucknow, Mangalore, Mumbai, Nagpur, Pune, Tiruchirapalli, Trivandrum, Varanasi & Vishakhapatnam) and 5 designated seaports (i.e. Cochin, Goa, Mangalore,Mumbai,Chennai). However, the foreigner can take exit from any of the authorized Immigration Check Posts (ICPs) in India.